# Laravel get object

Tags: php, laravel

I have small problems with my Laravel app.
I'm listing some data from my database, and I want to take specific object from each.

Code that works look like this.

```
    $user = auth()->user();
    $servers = Server::where('clientid', $user->id)
               ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
               ->get();


    if ($user) {
        $reposne['result'] = true;
        $reposne['servers'] = $server;
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }
    return $reposne;
}
```

And that is listing table, but I need to get id from every object I have there, like:

```
    if ($user) {
        $reposne['result'] = true;
        $reposne['separate_id'] = $server[]->id; 
        $reposne['servers'] = $server;
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    return $reposne;
}
```

But ofc, that don't work. I tried with foreach like:

```
foreach ($servers as $key => $server) {
    $data['id'] = $server->id;
}
if ($user) {
    $reposne['result'] = true;
    $reposne['servers'] = $data;
} else {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
}

return $reposne;
```

But it lists only first one.

Comment: You're overriding `$data['id']` in every loop...

Comment: `$data['id'] = $server->id;` ---> `$data['id'][] = $server->id;`

Answer (score 0):

You may use collection's `pluck` method:

```php
$ids = $server->pluck('id'); // retrieves all servers' IDs.
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-pluck) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the columns you want to pluck from the table using `pluck`.

```
$servers = Server::where('clientid', $user->id)
               ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
               ->pluck('id');
```